# Alias a Google Apps for Work email address to an Email with a different domain I don't own

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, google-apps-for-work

We use a third party recruiting SaaS and need job applications emailed to a unique email address provided by the recruiting software provider. I'd like to set up an email address such as apply@ourdomain.com which would alias so that the emails were actually sent to uniqueemail@recruitingsaas.com.

We can't have the emails forwarded as then the recruiting software will recognise all the emails as coming from apply@ourdomain.com and think that that is the person that applied, consider all applications duplicates and we would also be unable to reply to the applications from within the software.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Group email, that would direct all received mails from apply@ourdomain.com (Group) to the recruiting software's email and to the inbox where we want a copy to check them at the same time.

This is the only way I know that creates multiple copies of emails without passing through a forwarding process.